# Cleaning scraped url in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am writing a web scraper to scrape links from websites. It works fine but the output links are not clean. It outputs broken html links and also retrieves same html link. This is the code

```
links = re.findall('<a class=.*?href="?\'?([^"\'>]*)', sourceCode)
            for link in links:  
                print link
```

And this is how output looks like

```
/preferences?hl=en&someting
/preferences?hl=en&someting
/history/something
/history/something
/support?pr=something
/support?pr=something
http://www.web1.com/parameters
http://www.web1.com/parameters
http://www.web2.com/parameters
http://www.web2.com/parameters
```

I tried cleaning links which are not html using this regex

```
link = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', link)
                    print link
```

It cleans the url but adds square bracket to it. How to clean this to get without square bracket? How should I prevent printing the same url twice or multiple times

```
/preferences?hl=en&someting -> []
http://www.web1.com/parameters -> [http://www.web1.com/parameters]
```

Comment: Not a solution but a hint: if you use `Python` anyway, you may very well try [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org), which brings all these requirements out of the box (prevent duplicates, build a proper URL, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `[]` around matched items **because [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns list** of items

```
link = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', link)
# pay attention on iteration over set(links) and not links
for link in set(links):
    print link
```

Notice that I've added [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) creation into `for loop` to get only unique links in that way you would prevent printng same url.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
links = re.findall('href="(http.*?)"', sourceCode)
links = sorted(set(links))

for link in links:
    print(links)
```

This will get only links that begins with `http` in it and remove duplicates as well as sort them